# How to get SOAP API Access on an ArcGIS Online Map?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online, soap

I published a tiled map service to ArcGIS Online.

[This web site](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-online-map-and-geoservices/geoservices) reported that we would be able to access the ArcGIS Online maps via the SOAP API from our applications.

I check my first published map and under **Supported Interfaces**, I have REST but not SOAP options.

Does anyone know how I can can get SOAP access to my ArcGIS Online Map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you'll have SOAP access to **your** ArcGIS Online tiled service. See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/About_the_ArcGIS_Online_API/010q000000n7000000/

I think the link you gave says that the ArcGIS Online geoservices  (geocoding, routing, geometryservices) can be accessed thru both REST and SOAP.  It does not talk about tiled services you created yourself on www.arcgis.com